# How to scrape data from website without selenium,puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, axios, fetch

I need to fetch data from a site for my React app. I created a server and this Nodejs server returns a data in response when request from my React application.For example, I can get 5 lines of data (with requests,fetch,axios) from the website, **but I need to click a button for more**. I don't want to use frameworks such as Selenium, Puppeteer because after deploying and creating a server, there is a problem. Does anyone have any suggestions other than these?

I tried to use selenium,puppeteer as headless for this issue, but these caused problems during the deploy phase.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the network tab in the browser's devtools and watch what happens when you click the "more" button. It's likely the browser is sending a request that includes paging parameters (e.g. start, limit) and you can replicate that request in your code to get what you're after.